# Replace the Cord in Vertical Blinds

Tags: blinds

My cord in my vertical blinds is fraying and I am afraid it is going to break at any moment.  Has anyone restrung their blinds?  Where is the best place to get replacement cord and what do I need to know about restringing it? They are Bali Magnum Vertical Blinds.

Comment: Are they expensive blinds?

Comment: It looks like it would be around $150 to replace the unit.

Comment: It can be quite easy to do this, but I'm not sure how easy it's going to be to explain rather than demonstrate ;)

Comment: I've searched online for videos or instructions, but I haven't found anything.  Does anyone know of any resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called Bali, the manufacturer.  They were able to look up my order based on the number on a sticker on the blinds.  They said the entire headrail needs to be disassembled to replace the cord.  They cannot send me a cord and instructions. There is a lifetime warranty, but since the previous owner purchased it and my name was not on the warranty, the warranty is invalid.  It looks like I am purchasing a new blind.  They said you could buy just the headrail, but my wife would like a different color if we are going to have to take it down anyway.

If anyone has one of these blinds and you know who purchased it.  Make sure you use their name when you call or email them.

Comment: Wow. And don't buy the blind from the same manufacturer...no parts, no service, and no warranty!